# How to get skrollr.js working with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, skrollr

Skrollr.js seems to stop working when you go back to a page with turbolinks. It works just fine if you manually refresh the page again or go to the page through the data-no-turbolink link.

I have tried calling the function using all possible ways but still no luck, mainly:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
var s = skrollr.init(); 
});

$(document).on('ready page:change', function () {
    var s = skrollr.init(); 
    });
```

There's a similar question on here but the accepted answer was that you should just disable turbolinks. I'd like to know how to keep skrollr working with turbolinks enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out in the end.
You need to call skrollr normally then use skrollr.init().refresh(); on the new page or load page function for your pushstate plugin. So with turbolinks use this:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function () {
skrollr.init().refresh(); 
});
```

Hopefully this will save someone a lot of time.

Comment: Sir, your solution works very well. Thanks a lot. Indeed it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was call Skrollr `destroy()` method on the `page:before-change` event, I also modified skroll.js and namespaced these events (added `.skroll` to them):

```
_addEvent(window, 'resize.skroll orientationchange.skroll) …')
```

So after calling the destroy() method, also:

```
$(window).off("resize.skroll");
$(window).off("orientationchange.skroll");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured it out too. It's a lot simpler than all of this, all you need to is use `code` $(document).on('page:load', function () {
skrollr.init().refresh(); 
});

Comment: Sorry to sound ungrateful!